# Faliure message : NoSuchDriver Unable to obtain: Capabilities {browserName: MicrosoftEdge, ms:edgeOptions

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, selenium-java

While I'm trying to execute the program, the program is getting failed also the following is the failure message I'm getting and I'm unable to resolve this :

" WARNING: IOException running command [C:\Users\RAZI\AppData\Local\Temp\selenium-manager105348031911200259374836408092303\selenium-manager.exe, --browser, MicrosoftEdge, --output, json]: Cannot run program "C:\Users\RAZI\AppData\Local\Temp\selenium-manager105348031911200259374836408092303\selenium-manager.exe": CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied "
Could anyone help me to resolve this?

I've tried to execute the below code

Expectation: Is that the code will execute

Answer (score 0):

1. file is not executable

OR

2. file is not accessible

Review your access rights to that folder and file.